# error processing request on product page

Tags: product, theme, magento-1.6

I have install the sweet shop magento theme but when i click on product to see details it will showing an error `There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1220027742165`

then I go to `var/report` and find the error record file

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:85:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::displayProductStockStatus(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:3156:"#0 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/design/frontend/default/theme646/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(55): Varien_Object->__call('displayProductS...', Array)
#1 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/design/frontend/default/theme646/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(55): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View->displayProductStockStatus()
#2 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/royal/pub...')
#3 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#4 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#10 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/design/frontend/default/theme646/template/page/1column.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#11 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/royal/pub...')
#12 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#13 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultNoRouteAction()
#19 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('defaultNoRoute')
#20 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/royal/public_html/test/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/royal/public_html/test/royalwholesalecandy/index.php(85): Mage::run('royalwholesalec...', 'website')
#24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:69:"/royalwholesalecandy/jelly-belly-gummi-pet-cockroaches-24ct-5232.html";s:11:"script_name";s:30:"/royalwholesalecandy/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:20:"royalwholesalecandy1";}
```

so can anyone tell how to remove this error

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party theme

Answer (score 2):

The error message seams clear. You are calling the method `displayProductStockStatus` on an object that does not support this method.
Look in the file `app/design/frontend/default/theme646/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` at line 55 as the error message suggests.
This error does not appear in the default theme, because the default theme does not call such a method.
Either your theme is built wrong, or you are missing some module that overrides the product view block and adds this method.

Comment: While I agree this question is off-topic because of 3rd party extension, I like the way you pointing OP where to check to resolve it rather than just scaring OP by close request and downvoting blindly. Respect!